# Convenient utilities for spawning simultaneous processes with elisp and gathering the results?

Tags: process

Are there existing utility functions / libraries that are similar to Python's [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) module?

For example:

- Launch many processes, return when they are all complete (or return an object which can be queried).
- Limit the number of jobs that run at once.
- Some control over error handling (for example, exit if one of the processes fails), shut down other

Answer (score 1):

This is a utility function to address my own need for this kind of a function, some extra functionality could be added - for now though I find it quite useful.

```el
(defun call-process-parallel (args &rest keywords)
  "Return the result of commands in ARGS.

ARGS must be a list of commands (themselves a list of strings).

Optional keywords in KEYWORDS.

:idle FLOAT
  The time (in seconds) to idle between checking for each processes result.

:jobs INTEGER
  The maximum number of processes to run at once.

:output BOOL/FUNCTION
  The destination for the output.

  - nil: ignores output.
  - t: returns the result as an array of strings.
  - function: runs the function with argument index & string result arguments.

:progress-message STRING
  When set, show progress percentage."
  (let
    ( ;; Keyword arguments.
      (idle nil)
      (jobs nil)
      (output nil)
      (output-is-fn nil)
      (progress-message nil))

    ;; Parse keywords.
    (while keywords
      (let ((arg-current (car keywords)))
        (setq keywords (cdr keywords))
        (cond
          ((symbolp arg-current)
            (unless keywords
              (error "Keyword argument %S has no value!" arg-current))
            (let ((v (car keywords)))
              (setq keywords (cdr keywords))
              (pcase arg-current
                (:idle
                  (cond
                    ((null v)) ;; Ignore.
                    ((floatp v))
                    (t
                      (error "Argument :idle expected a float, not a %S" (type-of v))))
                  (setq idle v))

                (:jobs
                  (cond
                    ((null v)) ;; Ignore.
                    ((eq v t)) ;; String output (result vector)
                    ((symbolp v))
                    (t
                      (error "Output expected nil, t or a symbol")))
                  (setq jobs v))

                (:output
                  (cond
                    ((null v)) ;; Ignore.
                    ((eq v t)) ;; String output (result vector)
                    ((functionp v)
                      (setq output-is-fn t))
                    (t
                      (error "Output expected nil, t or a symbol, not a %S" (type-of v))))
                  (setq output v))

                (:progress-message
                  (cond
                    ((null v)) ;; Ignore.
                    ((stringp v)
                      (setq output-is-fn t))
                    (t
                      (error "Progress-message expected nil or string, not a %S" (type-of v))))
                  (setq progress-message v))

                (_ (error "Unknown argument %S" arg-current)))))
          (t
            (error
              "Optional arguments must be property pairs, found %S = %S"
              (type-of arg-current)
              arg-current)))))

    ;; Set defaults when unset.
    (unless idle
      (setq idle 0.01))

    ;; TODO: detect.
    (unless jobs
      (setq jobs
        (cond
          ((fboundp 'num-processors) ;; Emacs 29+
            (* 2 (num-processors)))
          (t
            (or diff-ansi-multiprocess-jobs 64)))))

    (let*
      (
        (args-len (length args))
        (results (make-vector args-len nil))
        (procs (make-vector args-len nil))
        (jobs-pending nil)
        (count-complete 0)
        (count-running 0)
        (no-error t)

        (output-funcall-next 0)

        (filter-job-fn
          (lambda (proc str)
            (let ((id (process-get proc :my-job-id)))
              (aset results id (cons str (aref results id))))))

        (sentinel-job-fn
          (lambda (proc _msg)
            (let ((id (process-get proc :my-job-id)))
              ;; Clear the process in the array so it's never touched again.
              (aset procs id nil)
              (let ((exit-code (process-exit-status proc)))
                (unless (zerop exit-code)
                  (setq no-error nil)
                  (error "Command exited code=%d: %S" exit-code (aref args id))))

              (delete-process proc)

              (setq count-complete (1+ count-complete))
              (setq count-running (1- count-running))
              (when output
                (let ((str (mapconcat #'identity (reverse (aref results id)) "")))
                  (aset results id str)))

              (when progress-message
                (let ((message-log-max nil))
                  (message
                    "%s%.2f%%"
                    progress-message
                    (* 100.0 (/ (float count-complete) args-len))))))))

        (start-job-fn
          (lambda (i)
            (setq count-running (1+ count-running))
            (let
              (
                (proc
                  (make-process
                    :name (concat "call-process-parallel" (number-to-string i))
                    ;; Write to the intermediate buffer or the final output.
                    :connection-type 'pipe
                    :command (aref args i)
                    :filter filter-job-fn
                    :sentinel sentinel-job-fn)))

              (process-put proc :my-job-id i)))))

      ;; Convert `args' to a vector for fast indexing.
      (setq args (vconcat args))

      ;; Setup indices to represent jobs that aren't complete.
      (let ((i args-len))
        (while (not (zerop i))
          (push (setq i (1- i)) jobs-pending)))

      ;; Main loop to complete
      (diff-ansi--with-temp-echo-area
        (while
          (progn
            ;; Run every time, important to run before exiting.
            (when output-is-fn
              (let
                (
                  (str nil)
                  (is-modified nil))
                (while
                  (and
                    (< output-funcall-next args-len)
                    (stringp (setq str (aref results output-funcall-next))))
                  ;; Overwrite with `t' (never to use again).
                  (funcall output output-funcall-next str)
                  (aset results output-funcall-next t)
                  (setq output-funcall-next (1+ output-funcall-next))
                  (setq is-modified t))
                (when is-modified

                  (redisplay))))

            ;; Check if exiting is needed.
            (and no-error (not (eq count-complete args-len))))

          ;; Fill the queue.
          (while (and jobs-pending (< count-running jobs))
            (funcall start-job-fn (pop jobs-pending)))

          (sleep-for idle)))

      (unless no-error
        (dotimes (i args-len)
          (let ((proc (aref procs i)))
            (when proc
              (delete-process proc)))))

      (cond
        ((eq output t)
          results)
        (t
          nil)))))
```